# mongoDb return results based on time interval

Tags: mongodb

I have this mongodb json data:

```
{'room' : '1', 'book_in_date' : '2013/09/11', 'book_out_date' : '2013/09/12'}
{'room' : '1', 'book_in_date' : '2013/09/15', 'book_out_date' : '2013/09/17'}
{'room' : '2', 'book_in_date' : '2013/09/11', 'book_out_date' : '2013/09/13'}
{'room' : '3', 'book_in_date' : '2013/09/20', 'book_out_date' : '2013/09/22'}
{'room' : '4', 'book_in_date' : '2013/09/09', 'book_out_date' : '2013/09/10'}
```

What I want to achieve is to get all rooms that conflicts with this time interval:

```
book_in_date = 2013/09/11
book_out_date = 2013/09/13
```

In above data example the result will be: room1(first record),room2.

Is this possible in mongodb?

Comment: Is it ok to change the format of your date fields to ISODate("2013-09-11T00:00:00.000Z") ?

Comment: It was just an example, in db they are ISODate

Comment: Cool, I have added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to follow this basic logic ([here's](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestIfDateRangesOverlap) a longer explanation and some links). Your example data doesn't cover a room in/out date that fully overlaps the selected range, so I'm covering that here.

```
start1 <= end2 AND start2 <= end1
```

Which in your case:

```
book_in_date <= room_end_date AND room_start_date <= book_out_date
```

As the query needs to use the room data, the first condition needs to be flipped around slightly:

```
room_out_date => 2013/09/11 AND room_in_date <= 2013/09/13
```

(But, you've used `book_start/out_date`, so, it's really as shown below)

So, that's translated to:

```
rooms.find({ $and: [ 
                { book_out_date : { $gte : ISODate("2013-09-11") } },
                { book_in_date : { $lte : ISODate("2013-09-13") } } 
            ]);
```

#### Tests

Given this data:

```
{ "room" : "1", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-07T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-08T00:00:00Z") }
{ "room" : "1", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-11T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-12T00:00:00Z") }
{ "room" : "2", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-15T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-17T00:00:00Z") }
{ "room" : "3", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-11T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-13T00:00:00Z") }
{ "room" : "4", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-20T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-22T00:00:00Z") }
{ "room" : "5", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-09T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-10T00:00:00Z") }
```

And this query:

```
> db.interval.find(
     {$and: [ 
        { book_out_date: { $gte: ISODate('2013-09-09')}},
        {book_in_date: { $lte: ISODate('2013-09-11')}}]} )
```

Results:

```
{ "room" : "1", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-11T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-12T00:00:00Z") }
{ "room" : "3", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-11T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-13T00:00:00Z") }
{ "room" : "5", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-09T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-10T00:00:00Z") }
```

Another:

```
> db.interval.find({$and: [ { book_out_date: { $gte: ISODate('2013-09-01')}}, {book_in_date: { $lte: ISODate('2013-09-19')}}]} )
```

Results:

```
{ "room" : "1", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-07T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-08T00:00:00Z") }
{ "room" : "1", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-11T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-12T00:00:00Z") }
{ "room" : "2", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-15T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-17T00:00:00Z") }
{ "room" : "3", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-11T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-13T00:00:00Z") }
{ "room" : "5", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-09T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-10T00:00:00Z") }
```

Another:

```
> db.interval.find({$and: [ { book_out_date: { $gte: ISODate('2013-09-22')}}, {book_in_date: { $lte: ISODate('2013-09-24')}}]} )
```

Results:

```
{ "room" : "4", "book_in_date" : ISODate("2013-09-20T00:00:00Z"), "book_out_date" : ISODate("2013-09-22T00:00:00Z") }
```

Comment: {'room': 1, 'book_in_date' : 2013/09/07, 'book_out_date' : 2013/09/08}
{'room': 1, 'book_in_date' : 2013/09/11, 'book_out_date' : 2013/09/12}

If my searched range is:
1. 2013/09/06-07 --- 2013/09/08-09 # I get correct data
2. 2013/09/09 --- 2013/09/11 # Bad response, second record is not in the result

Comment: I don't understand what's not working as your syntax doesn't make sense. What's `2013/09/06-07?` I've added a bunch of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possilbe, your query would look like this:

```
rooms.find({ $or [{ book_in_date: { $gte: yourBookInDate }, 
                    book_out_date: { $lte: yourBookOutDate }},
                  { book_in_date: { $lte: yourBookOutDate }, 
                    book_out_date: { $gte: yourBookOutDate }}
                  { book_in_date: { $lte: yourBookInDate }, 
                    book_out_date: { $gte: yourBookInDate }}]
            }).toArray(function(err, result) {
                   //process result
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query would return the desired results:

```
db.library.find({'book_in_date' : {$gte:new ISODate('2013-09-11T00:00:00.000Z')},'book_out_date' : {$lte: new ISODate('2013-09-13T00:00:00.000Z')}})
```

Comment: There are cases that this misses. Think about ranges that contain those dates for example.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I am not sure it does. From the sample data provided in question, the results returned must be greater than or equal to '2013/09/11' and less than or equal to '2013/09/13'. $gte checks for greater than and equal to while $lte checks for less than and equal to!