# how to export last 15 mins data from mongo collection using mongo export

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoose

I have a conn_time field in the collection,need to export last 15 mins data from the collection using mongo export .conn_time date is in ISO format.
date format like 2013-06-11T07:18:00Z. I have tried using JavaScript like but not working

```
var enDdate = new Date(); enDdate.toISOString()
var startDate = new Date(endDate-15*60*1000); startDate.toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this question: [mongoDb return results based on time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675468/mongodb-return-results-based-on-time-interval)

You have to escape the spec chars. I could not make it run with the ISODate helper but like this

`"{date:{\$gt:{ \"\$date\" : 1370935140000 }}}"`

given as a -q parameter to the mongoexport works fine. This case  1370935140000 is the unix timestamp in mili secs. So you have to calculate the unixtimestamp 15 mins before than add 000 at the and and go on with this. I will try to resolve also with the ISODate.